# Existence of Solutions to Elliptic Equations on Compact Manifolds -- Global Obstructions?

Tags: differential-geometry, elliptic-equations, linear-pde

Let $(M,g)$ be a smooth, closed Riemannian manifold and let $X$ and $c$ respectively be a smooth vector field and a smooth function on $M$. Do there exist general criteria for determining for which smooth functions $f$ there exists a smooth solution to the elliptic PDE
$$\Delta u +X(u) +cu =f?$$
I'm familiar with the local theory which guarantees for us the existence of local solutions in any coordinate patch but there seem to be global obstructions once we move to the manifold setting. For example, in the instance that $X$ and $c$ are both identically $0$, there is a clear global obstruction to the problem, namely whether or not the integral of $f$ over $M$ vanishes (one can show, using the heat flow [or sheaf cohomology in the instance that $M$ is a Kähler] that, in this instance, this is in fact the only obstruction). I believe that in the case that either $c \geq 0$ or $c \leq 0$ the local theory combined with sheaf cohomology tells us that the answer is essentially the same as for the Laplacian, but if we don't have control over $c$, then what happens?

Any and all insights are welcomed!

Comment: Are you familiar with the *index* of a Fredholm operator?

Comment: Yes. The Atiyah-Singer index theorem should be able to relate for me the dimension of the kernel to the dimension of the cokernel but this won't help unless I know something about the kernel, right? Or am I missing something? Thanks for the response in any event!

Comment: What happens when continuing a local solution along a closed curve  ? (there is a linear map acting on the space of solution for $f=0$)

Comment: Well, in general, the space of local homogeneous solutions is quite large so I don't know how to get a handle on that (take for instance the case of the Laplacian -- the space of harmonic functions on the unit ball is in general uncountably infinite) but I'm running thin on ideas for this. Any suggestions? I don't know what linear map you're referring to but I assume you're trying to use sheaf-theoretic reasoning here?

Comment: No need to employ the (deep) Atiyah-Singer theorem. It is well-known that the index of the Laplacian is zero. But your operator only differs from the Laplacian by lower order terms, which are compact, and is thus of index zero, too. In particular, if your operator is one-to-one (and this is "usually" the case, in some sense), it is also onto.

Comment: Okay, awesome, thank you so much for your informative answer. It's seems I need to do a deeper dive on Fredholm theory. Am I correct in saying that if the operator admits an orthonormal eigenbasis in some Hilbert space then the obstruction is the projection of $f$ onto the $0$ eigenspace?